# gdal_polygonize slow

Tags: qgis, gdal, gdal-polygonize

I am trying to convert 1400 tiff files to GeoJson..tif file size ranges from 20 mb to 1Gb.
gdal_polygonize.py  is taking 24 hours for Big files 5 hours for small files.

Any way to improve performance?

Comment: What is your GDAL version? Check with `gdalinfo --version`.

Comment: GDAL 3.0.2..i am on Linux

Comment: Some work was done for improving the building of complex polygons in https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/pull/2908. That deals directly with gdal_dem but if could be worth trying if GDAL 3.2 is faster also with gdal_polygonize.

Answer (score 0):

Someone suggested using PostGIS tools `raster2pgsql` and `ST_DumpAsPolygons` in response to my [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/463754/gdal-polygonize-taking-a-long-time-in-qgis?noredirect=1#comment757387_463754), saying that it is very fast (but seems to have deletet the comment later).
For Footprints there is now `gdal_footprint`